# Bootstrap embeded video disables sound button

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am embeding video files from sql table into  tags. I can play the video, everything is okay with that, but the sound or mute button is always diabled, i cant to anything with it.

Whats the problem?

```
echo '<video style="width:inherit" class="video-fluid z-depth-1" controls muted>
                            <source src="'.$host.'/videok/'.$vid['video_fajl'].'" type="video/mp4" />
                         </video>';
```

Comment: would it have to do with `controls muted` right after the class?

Comment: Sorry, i dont unserstand. I tryed it also without these classes, but still the same problem.